# How to determine image width for small screen only in portrait view?

Tags: html, css

I want a banner to be displayed over 50% of the width of a large screen (desktop) and 100% of the width on a small screen (iphone) when it is portrait view. When it is in landscape view it must be 50%.

At the moment I have

```
.advert-img {
  width: 50%
  height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .advert-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

How would I take retina displays into account?

Comment: media query supports `orientation`. Use it like `@media (max-width: 380px) and (orientation: portrait) { ... }`. Also there is a specific query which might work for retina devices, `@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}`. You can try and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To take into account retina displays you can use the following css

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Hope this helps